# how does fast-exif works under ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to use under ionic 4 "fast-exif".

https://github.com/titarenko/fast-exif

And I don't arrive to make it works

`var exif = require('fast-exif');`
doesn't work under ionic 4

*Edited to show the code:*

```
const exif = require('fast-exif');
const img = files[0];
exif.read(img).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Someone can help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Hi JBD, can you please share your code with us? It's helpful and we might be able to help you with your question.

Comment: Yes .... I've edited the post... I just did what it's written in the doc and I got this error message: ```ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts:32:18 - error TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'```

Comment: are you using camera plugin if yes try this: https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif

Comment: I'm not using camera plugin. It's just a simple <input type="file">